# Unable to roll over date to 2015

Tags: jquery, datetime

I have a script that gets me the date of `lastmonth`, `current month` and `next month`. See below

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var d = new Date();
   var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",     
          "September", "October", "November", "December"];
   var pastmonth = monthNames[d.getMonth() - 1].toString();
   alert('Past Month: ' + pastmonth);
   var monthlymonth = monthNames[d.getMonth()].toString();
   alert('Current Month: ' + monthlymonth);
   var futuremonth = monthNames[d.getMonth() + 1].toString();
   alert('Future Month: ' + futuremonth);
   //Error over here and I am not sure why
 });
```

I think the problem is that adding a month to our current month , will roll over into a new year `2015` and then it breaks.

I have been reading a few SO threads and cannot really find an answer for this. It broke as we entered `December` and has been working fine for all other `2014` Months.

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/km77nhch/1/) of the issue.

Anybody experienced the same problem and could help me out with some links to threads that may help me?

**EDIT:** Essentially - What I need future month to be is `January`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have array of months and trying to access `var futuremonth = monthNames[d.getMonth() + 1].toString();`. Here `d.getMonth() + 1` is 13 and month has only 12 elements; hence giving you the array out of index exception.

You can overcome this problem by using `%12` for calculating monthNames array index.

Try below code :

```
var pastmonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() - 1)%12].toString();
                  alert('Past Month: ' + pastmonth);


var monthlymonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth())%12].toString();
                  alert('Current Month: ' + monthlymonth);


var futuremonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() + 1)%12].toString();
                  alert('Future Month: ' + futuremonth);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/km77nhch/5/)**

**EDIT** - Above solution will fail if Current month is JANUARY where `d.getMonth()=0`, to overcome this problem you need to update below code -

```
var pastmonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() > 0)?((d.getMonth() - 1)%12):11].toString();
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks so much Bhushan... Could you explain to me what that `%12` does?

Comment: You have total 12 months in array and if month index goes beyond 12 then we need to go to the start of array again and get month value. Here `%12` gives you the remainder of number and calculate the next month correctly.

Comment: @Mike In simple `%` (modules) represents remainder (12 % 12 = 0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use modulus % operator, so when the future value of the month becomes 12 it changes to 0, which avoids the index out of bounds error with the monthNames array:

```
    var futuremonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() + 1)%12].toString();
          alert('Future Month: ' + futuremonth);
```

**Updated**, also for the past month, you could use sth like following:

```
     var pastmonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() == 0) ? 11 : d.getMonth()-1].toString();
           alert('Past Month: ' + pastmonth);
```

So when it's January, the past month will be December.

[Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/km77nhch/14/)

Comment: This will fail for current month `JANUARY` as `pastmonth` will display as `JANUARY` if current month is `JANUARY` for the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Date method of JS will work as you mentioned.

for example:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(12);
alert(d) // Jan 02 2015
```

Whereas you are trying to customize by showing the month in english terms, so you have to do your own implementation like

```
var futuremonth = monthNames[(d.getMonth() + 1) % 12].toString();
```